# How to fill unused memory with software reset instruction on SAMC21 controller in XC32 compiler?

Tags: command-line-interface, microchip, mplab, sam, xc32

I am using SAMC21 controller and xc32 compiler. I want to fill my all unused ROM memory with the software reset instruction. Does anyone know, what is the command line option for performing software reset from XC32 compiler.

IDE - MPLABX
Compiler - XC32
Microcontroller - SAMC21

Answer (score 1):

The `--FILL` driver option allows you to fill the unused program memory with a known value.
You can access this option in the MPLAB® X IDE

> XC32 Project Properties > XC32 Linker > Fill Flash Memory

Comment: Fill option i saw, we can fill the known value in unused location, but actually i am searching for software reset instruction, which reset the micro controller ROM memory.

Comment: You could add the code for the RESET instruction as a fill value. I am not familar with MIPS. Is there a RESET instruction? Maybe add the code for a jump to address `0x000000`

Comment: I went through compiler and linker manual, but i did not find a reset instruction